# Create function which performers different operations depending on the input slice argument

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I just started to learn Go language and I want to build a function which will be selecting a random subsequence from a slice. However, I don't know what type of values this slice can store, these can be integers, strings or elements of some struct. For example, let's assume I have to structures:

```
type person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

type animal struct {
    name  string
    age   int
    breed string
}
```

Now, I want to build function getRandomSequence as follows: given as arguments a slice S and a length l the function returns a slice which contains l randomly selected elements from slice S. The problem which I encountered was - how to make this function work for any possible slice. I tried to do the following:

```
func GetRandomSequence(S interface{}, l int) []interface{} {
   switch S.(type) {
   case person:
      // Do random selection of l elements from S and return them
   case animal:
      // Do random selection of l elements from S and return them
   case int:
     // Do random selection of l elements from S and return them
   }
   return " Not Recognised"
}
```

Can someone suggest how I can write such function? I manage to make similar (i.e., general) functions work if S would be a single element of any type (so instead of `[]interface{}` would be just `interface{}`) but I cannot find out how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to perform the same operation on different slice types as implied by the body of the question, or are you asking what the title says?

Comment: If you are new to Go the best advice would be to not fight the language and to _not_ write such a function, but e.g. two or three.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `interface{}` not `[]interface{}`. An empty interface can store any type, including slices.

Your code would look something like this (although I didn't test):

```
func GetRandomSequence(S interface{}, l int) interface{} {
   returnSlice := []interface{}
   switch v := s.(type) {
   // inside the switch v has the value of S converted to the type
   case []person:
      // v is a slice of persons here
   case []animal:
      // v is a slice of animals here
   case []int:
      // v is a slice of ints here
   case default:
       // v is of type interface{} because i didn't match any type on the switch
       // I recommend you return nil on error instead of a string
       // or always return 2 things, the value and an error like 
       // the standard library
       return "Not Recognized" 
   }
   rerurn returnSlice
}
```

I recommend you do the complete [Tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/), but for this question the answer is [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16).

Depending on what you want to do exactly, it looks like you might not need different types of slices but a slice of `interface{}`. If in your function to extract random elements from the slice you don't care about the type of the elements just do:

```
func GetRandomSequence(S []interface{}, l int) []interface{} {
    returnSlice := make([]interface{}, 0, l)
    for i:=0; i<l; i++ { 
        // S[i] here is always of type interface{}
        returnSlice = append(returnSlice, S[getRnd()]) // you need to implement getRnd() or just "math/rand" or something.
    }
    return returnSlice 
}
```